# The requested resource [/login] is not available

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

I am finishing my first web application with Spring Boot implementing Spring security, everything works fine in the IDE before the deployment, even after the deployment in apache-tomcat when I go to the application through the browser everything appears normal at the beginning including the login form, but when entering the credentials and pressing the enter button it sends me the following exception: "The requested resource [/ login] is not available". I don't understand if everything works fine in the IDE. If someone could help me solve this problems I would be very grateful, I share the code of the configuration classes:

[HTTP 404 - Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUOBI.jpg)

The spring security class:

```
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)  
@Configuration
public class MantprevSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
/*************************************************************************/
    
    @Autowired 
    private UsuariosService serviceUsuarios;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
        
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    /*************************************************/
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configurerGlobal (AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    /*************************************************************************************/
        builder.userDetailsService(serviceUsuarios).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);  
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    /**************************************************************/
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();  //Evita el error al enviar contenido al iFrame
        
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/resources/**", "/WEB-INF/views/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()    //.defaultSuccessUrl("/tools/getResumenMantto", true)
                .and().logout().permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error_403"); ///WEB-INF/views/errors/error_403        
    }
    
    @Override  //Ignora bloqueos de seguridad para los archivos que estan en resources
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    /***************************************/
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }  
}
```

my login controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
/*****************************/
        
    @GetMapping ("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) String error,
                        @RequestParam(value="logout", required=false) String logout,
                        Model model, Principal principal, RedirectAttributes flash, Authentication usuario) {
    /********************************************************************************************************/
        
        if (principal != null) { //Si el usuario ya ha hecho login no vuelve a pedir login
            flash.addFlashAttribute("mensaje", " Usted ya tiene una sesión abierta !!!");
            return "redirect:/";
        }
        
        if(error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("mensaje", " Error en el login: el nombre de usuario o contraseña es incorrecta, por favor inténtelo nuevamente !!!");
        }
        
        if(logout != null) {
            model.addAttribute("mensaje2", " Usted ha cerrado su sesión del MantPrev con éxito !!!");
        }
        
        return "login";
    }
}
```

The Initializar class:

```
package com.mantprev;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;


public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
/*********************************************************************/
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    /***********************************************************************************/
        return application.sources(MantprevWebWarApplication.class);
    }
    
}
```

The aplication class:

package com.mantprev;

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;


public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
/*********************************************************************/
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    /***********************************************************************************/
        return application.sources(MantprevWebWarApplication.class);
    }
    
}
```

my login.jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Mantprev Login</title>
    
    <spring:url value="/resources" var="urlResources" />
    
    <link href="${urlResources}/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <style>
        body {background-image: url(${urlResources}/images/DefBackground.jpg);}
        
        .container{margin-top: 100px;}
        
        #loginFrame {width: 500px; margin: auto; border: 2px solid #4d94ff;
                    border-radius: 10px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;}
        
        .picture {margin: 15px auto; height: 140px; width: 140px;} /* border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 5px;  */
        
        #username, #password {background-color: #f5f5ef; font-size: 120%; }
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>

    <input type="hidden" id="urlResources" value="${urlResources}"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="context" value="context">

    <c:if test="${mensaje != null}">
        <br>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" style="width: 1100px; margin: auto; text-align: center;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>Problema!!!: </strong> ${mensaje}
        </div>
    </c:if>
    
    <c:if test="${mensaje2 != null}">
        <br>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" style="width: 1100px; margin: auto; text-align: center;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>Exito!!!. </strong> ${mensaje2}
        </div>
    </c:if>
    
    <div class="container">
    
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h4>MANTPREV</h4>
            <h5>Sistema para Mantenimiento Industrial</h5>
        </div>
    
        <div class="text-center" id="loginFrame">
        
            <div class="picture" >
                 <img src="${urlResources}/images/login.png" width="139" height="139" class="center"> 
            </div>
    
            <div class="text text-center" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <h6>Digite su nombre de Usuario y su Password</h6>
            </div>
            
            <form method="POST" action="/login" >  <%-- ${urlMainMenu} --%>
            
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus required />
                 </div>    
                    
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                 </div>    
                    
                 <div class="form-group">   
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Ingresar al MantPrev</button>
                 </div> 
                    
                 <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        
            </form>
            
        </div>
    
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster   
    ======================================================================== -->
    <script src="${urlResources}/bootstrap/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="${urlResources}/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it is failing when deployed to tomcat we need to see your build file.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem !!!. In the login.jsp I had to had written the contextpath in the action of the form. This way:

```
<form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">
```

Now everything is working fine.